# Unable to pop the Navigation Library's back stack

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation

I have some trouble with popping the back stack when using the navigation library.

I have the following flow

> - Secondary Graph FragSecondA -> FragSecondB
> - Main Graph FragMainA -> FragMainB -> FragMainC -> SecondaryGraph
> - I'd like to clear FragMainA, FragMainB, FragMainC from the back stack once I reach FragSecondA.

I tried using setting `app:popUpTo="@id/fragment_main_c" app:popUpToInclusive="true"` on the action that leads to the Secondary Graph. Using the code I mentioned will only pop FragMainC from the back stack leaving me to navigate back to FragMainB. I tried setting `app:clearTask=true` which gets me the desired result, however this method as deprecated.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I might fix this issue without having to use the deprecated method?

Comment: U should Read All Document:https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/

Comment: Yeah, thanks for that, it was just my poor understanding of the stack... Figured it out now and it's clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below it should work.

edit your action_fragMainC_to_secondaryGraph

```
            <action
            android:id="@+id/action_fragMainC_to_secondaryGraph"
            app:destination="@id/secondary_nav_graph"
            app:popUpTo="@+id/main_nav_graph" />
```